# android: adding to options menu dynamically

Tags: android, menu

I am just trying to add other activities to my options menu
I have my app which displays its menu defined as

```
public class OptionsMenuTesterActivity extends Activity {
        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
        }
        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

            // Create an Intent that describes the requirements to fulfill, to be included
            // in our menu. The offering app must include a category value of Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE. 
            Intent intent = new Intent(null,getIntent().getData());
            intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);

            // Search for, and populate the menu with, acceptable offering applications.
            menu.addIntentOptions(
                    Menu.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE,  // Menu group 
                 0,      // Unique item ID (none)
                 0,      // Order for the items (none)
                 this.getComponentName(),   // The current Activity name
                 null,   // Specific items to place first (none)
                 intent, // Intent created above that describes our requirements
                 0,      // Additional flags to control items (none)
                 null);  // Array of MenuItems that corrolate to specific items (none)

            return true;
        }
    }
```

now i have created another simple app with one activity and its androidmaifest looks as below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.idg.test.dynamicoptionsmenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DynamicOptionsMenuTesterActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter label="test menu">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />

            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

i have both applications launched. But when i click on the menu of first app, i dont see anything
Can you help me telling what i am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openOptionsMenu() { 
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
    super.openOptionsMenu(); 
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    //call the base class to include system menus
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

        int group1 = 1;
        MenuItem bakchome = menu.add(group1,1,1,"title");
        bakchome.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_add);

    return true;
}

@Override 
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case 1:

        Intent intent1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), yourintent.class);
        intent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent1);
            break;

        }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit older, but I it took me a while to complete it, so maybe it will save others some time and frustration. Hope it helps...

Here is what I did to create my dynamic menu to offer all available options to share an image. I've build my own topmenu instead of using the ActionBar. My menu item starts on an `ImageButton` in the `onCreate` method of the `Activity`...

```
    ImageButton shareBtn = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.shareBtn);
    shareBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        // receive launchables (to build menu items)
        List<ResolveInfo> launchables = getLaunchablesToShareWith();
        PackageManager pm=getPackageManager();

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Creating the instance of PopupMenu
            PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), v);

            //enable icons using Reflection...
            try {
                Field[] fields = popup.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
                for (Field field : fields) {
                    if ("mPopup".equals(field.getName())) {
                        field.setAccessible(true);
                        Object menuPopupHelper = field.get(popup);
                        Class<?> classPopupHelper = Class.forName(menuPopupHelper
                                .getClass().getName());
                        Method setForceIcons = classPopupHelper.getMethod(
                                "setForceShowIcon", boolean.class);
                        setForceIcons.invoke(menuPopupHelper, true);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            //Inflating the Popup using xml file
            popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popupmenu_your_activity, popup.getMenu());

            // add items
            for (ListIterator<ResolveInfo> iterator = launchables.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {

                // extract data from launchables
                ResolveInfo resolveInfo = iterator.next();
                String title = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(pm).toString();
                String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.applicationInfo.packageName;
                Drawable appIcon = null;
                try {
                    appIcon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageName);
                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    continue;
                }

                // create & add item
                popup.getMenu().add(0, 0, 0, title)
                                .setIcon(appIcon)
                                .setIntent( getShareIntent().setPackage(packageName) )
                                .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                                        prepareImageToShare(true);
                                        startActivity(item.getIntent());
                                        return true;
                                    }
                                });
            }

            popup.show();
        }
    });
```

To create the launchables list:

```
private List<ResolveInfo> getLaunchablesToShareWith() {
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND, null);
    intent.setType("image/png");

    List<ResolveInfo> launchables=pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    Collections.sort(launchables, new ResolveInfo.DisplayNameComparator(pm));

    return launchables;
}
```

To create the share `Intent`:

```
private Intent getShareIntent() {
    // File helper returns something like return Uri.parse("file:///storage/emulated/0/YourApp/output/image.png");
    Uri imageUri = FileHelper.getOutputPathAsUri(Files.SHARED_OUTPUT_FILE.getFilename(), Paths.OUTPUT_FOLDER_PATH.getPath(), true); 

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setData(imageUri);
    shareIntent.setType("image/png");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);

    return shareIntent;
}
```

The menu layout file (**popupmenu_your_activity.xml**) looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="your.package.YourActivity" >

    <!-- popup menu with dynamic content -->

</menu>
```